# iphone jailbreak - its asking for active sim card

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, sim, unlock

i'm in china and need to jailbreak/unlock my iphone to use it here with chinese sim card. I followed the instructions online about how to do this using a program called snowbreeze. It worked and i believe the iphone now has ios 4.3.1 and the ipad baseband. However, in order to unlock the thing i need to get into it, and it is asking me to insert 'a valid sim card with no PIN  lock to active iPhone.

Not sure what i should do here? I lost my tmobile sim card in a hotel and don't have one. Is it necessary to insert a tmobile sim card just to turn the phone on? (Also my sim card has a pin on it so how can even that work?). If this is the answer then i will try my gf's tmobile sim card. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of stating what you've probably already tried... Insert the Chinese sim card you want to use.